# Django sessions for anonymous users

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

I want to be able to collect basic stats on the use of a webapp by users, both anonymous and logged-in.

The commonality here would be that using session ids, I could store data for both logged-in and logged-out users, and still be able to link the stored stats to a given session (who the session belongs to is immaterial).

However, I'm running into issues with collecting the `session_key`, as this does not appear to be set when an anonymous user enters the site (presumably because of the fact Django sessions are [only saved when modified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

When I test a view with a logged-in user:

```
def create(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print request.session.session_key
```

For a logged in user, the `session_key` is printed. For a logged out user or anonymous user this is `None`. On first request to the site, the session does not exist and consequently is not available to the view.

My current plan is to create a custom Middleware as a subclass of the official session middleware, but overriding `process_request()` to instantiate sessions for those who do not have one via `session.save()`.

My only concern with this approach is that I'm not sure if it will have unforeseen consequences for other parts of Django - do people have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd create a new middleware that does just that, for me it seems more robust and less likely to break in the future.

Answer (score 11):

In a past project I did what you are suggesting but just within a view where I needed to use `session_key` for unauthenticated visitors. It did not cause any problems in my project:

```
if not request.session or not request.session.session_key:
   request.session.save()

# request.session.session_key now set
```

Answer (score -4):

You can choose to save session every request by setting:

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

This force django to assign the session key for each session

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

Comment: simply wrong, this does not set a session cookie for anonymous users